# How can I allow a Vec of custom type to be joined with &str?

Tags: string, rust, vector, traits

I want a `Vec<CustomType>` to be joinable by `&str`. Here is what I've tried so far:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Item {
    string: String,
}

impl Item {
    pub fn new(string: impl Into<String>) -> Self {
        Self {
            string: string.into(),
        }
    }

    pub fn to_string(&self) -> &String {
        &self.string
    }
}

impl From<&Item> for &String {
    fn from(item: &Item) -> Self {
        &item.string
    }
}

impl From<&Item> for &str {
    fn from(item: &Item) -> Self {
        &item.string.to_string()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let items = Vec::from([Item::new("Hello"), Item::new("world")]);
    let string = items.join(" ");
    println!("{}", string);
}
```

Which results in the error:

```
 $ rustc jointrait.rs 
error[E0599]: the method `join` exists for struct `Vec<Item>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> jointrait.rs:32:24
   |
32 |     let string = items.join(" ");
   |                        ^^^^ method cannot be called on `Vec<Item>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `[Item]: Join<_>`
```

The rustc help just says that some method is missing, but googling the error, I could not find out which method / trait I need to implement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for a list of `T`s to be joinable, `[T]` needs to implement [`Join<Separator>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.join).

If you look which things already implement `Join`, you will find the [following entry](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.Join.html#impl-Join%3C%26str%3E-for-%5BS%5D):

```
impl<S> Join<&str> for [S]
where
    S: Borrow<str>
```

This means, everything that implements `Borrow<str>` can be joined by a `&str` separator. So all you have to do is implement `Borrow<str>` for your struct:

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Item {
    string: String,
}

impl Item {
    pub fn new(string: impl Into<String>) -> Self {
        Self {
            string: string.into(),
        }
    }
}

impl Borrow<str> for Item {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &str {
        &self.string
    }
}

fn main() {
    let items = Vec::from([Item::new("Hello"), Item::new("world")]);
    let string = items.join(" ");
    println!("{}", string);
}
```

```
Hello world
```